# can't create a paremeterless constructor for a UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, asp.net-4.0

I have a web User Control (.ascx file) and I would like to initialize some private members.  But if I try to create a parameterless constructor like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="MyControl" %>

public MyControl() { }
```

I get the error:

> Type 'ASP.MyControl' already defines a member called 'MyControl'
>   with the same parameter types

with a source file that's under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem.  How I solved it was to create a base class with a method that I will use in the user control to do whatever it is that needs doing.

(Edit:  I forgot to mention that my base class is also marked abstract)

In the base class define:

```
public abstract void DoSomethingSpecial();
```

The base class calls this in it's own constructor:

```
public MyBaseClass()
{
    DoSomethingSpecial();
}
```

Then in the usercontrol I inherit the base class in the page directives:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyAppNamespace.myBaseClass" ... %>
```

The final step is to actually implement the new method in the usercontrol:

```
 public override void DoSomethingSpecial()
```

That was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize private members directly or, if they are properties, in your control's Page_Load event handler:

```
private int _myNumber = 19;

protected Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeMyPrivateProperties();
}
```

Comment: Page_Load is too late... even Page_Init is too late.  I want to initialize the properties before they are set by the calling .aspx page

Comment: Then I'm afraid only the direct initialization (as in the first line of the code sample above) is your only choice... That, or not creating an ASCX (user control) but rather a Webcontrol.

Comment: I can't use direct initialization with a property